# Sharp jagged lines in Plot3D

Tags: plotting, complex

I have the following function of five parameters of which I would like to construct a 3D density plot using `Plot3D`

```
d = 4 (12 g1^2 + 12 g2^2 + 12 g3^2 - Γ^2 + Γ κ1 - κ1^2 + (Γ + κ1) κ2 - κ2^2)^3 + (36 g1^2 (Γ + κ1 - 2 κ2) + (36 g3^2 - (Γ + κ1 - 2 κ2) (2 Γ - κ1 - κ2)) (Γ - 2 κ1 + κ2) + 36 g2^2 (-2 Γ + κ1 + κ2))^2
```

I then do

```
solg3 = g3 /.Solve[d == 0, g3] /. {Γ -> 0.01, κ1 -> 1, κ2 -> 20};
```

And plot

```
Plot3D[solg3, {g1, 0, 2.5}, {g2, 0, 8}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, RegionFunction -> Function[{g1, g2, solg3}, solg3 >= 0]]
```

I am returned with

[image]

At this point, I am seeing a lot of jagged lines on the contour and I'm not sure why this is happening. Firstly, it can be seen that there are six solutions to `solg3` but I only want positive values of `g3` hence there are only three contours. However, I'm puzzled by the appearance of those jagged lines on the lower edges of the contour surface. Why is this happening? And why are there gaps? Is it saying that `g3` is complex in those regions?

Comment: try the option `MaxRecursion` with a large value (say `MaxRecursion -> 10`) and increase `PlotPoints` (say `PlotPoints->200`)

Comment: If you don't know this, the LeafCount of solg3 is about 2800. peek at the FullForm of your function to see what you are expecting it to precisely plot. Simplify makes it even worse! Is there any way you can simplify that function 50 or 100 fold? PlotPoints->5 makes it less jagged, but I'm expecting that won't be acceptable either.

Comment: @kglr The plot is still simplifying past 20 minutes. I do not think that having MaxRecursion of 10 and PlotPoints of 200 is tractable. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Bill That is the best I can do in simplifying `d`. And PlotPoints of 5 is not enough. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a job for `ContpurPlot3D`:

```
dd = d /. {Γ -> 0.01, κ1 -> 1, κ2 -> 20};
ContourPlot3D[
 dd == 0,
 {g1, 0, 2.5}, {g2, 0, 8}, {g3, 0, 4},
 AxesLabel -> {"g1", "g2", "g3"},
 MaxRecursion -> 5
 ]
```

[image]

The result is still a bit jagged (at other places; try also different values of `MaxRecursion`), but much less.

Comment: Thanks this looks like what I'm looking for! My question is, given that the solution to `dd == 0` has 6 solutions, shouldn't I be seeing 6 different contours? Or at least 3 of them since the other 3 is simply the negative of the former.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D` employs purely numerical techniques (most likely bisection techniques for root finding). This is why it cannot distinguish the algebraic branches of the solition set. `ContourPlot3D`  does apply different colors for different levelsets, though.

Comment: The equations might have six solutions in the complex numbers. Notice however, that (i) we limit the search range by `{g1, 0, 2.5}, {g2, 0, 8}, {g3, 0, 4}` and that (ii) `ContourPlot3D` ignores all nonreal solutions.

Comment: I will have to look up on applying the colors separately for separate contours on the plot. I would, ideally, match the colors that I obtained from `Plot3D` but I'm skeptical of the plot regions, especially the jagged ones.